# How to set the Cache Control header with Paperclip / fog for a file hosted on Google storage?

Tags: paperclip, google-cloud-storage, fog, fog-google

I'm able to upload files to my google storage bucket with Paperclip and fog-google.

How can I set file headers ? I am searching for an equivalent to s3_headers option in fog-aws.

I have tried google_headers and fog_headers options with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go :

```
fog_file: {
   cache_control: 'max-age=86400'
}
```